# Export from KWD (old KWord/KOffice document format) to anything else

Tags: kde, documents

I've got 75 documents in KWD format, from my old days using KDE 3.x. I'd like to convert them to ODT or RTF, so I can edit them with Open Office, Abiword or the newer KWord, but I haven't found a good/quick way to do it.

Opening them in an old version of KWord and exporting them works, but if I have to do it for the 75 of them it'll take me ages. I've tried using `koconverter`, a batch converter for KOffice documents included in KDE libs, but neither the one from KOffice 1.6.x nor the one from 2.2.x works.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "I've tried using koconverter, a batch converter for KOffice documents included in KDE libs, but neither the one from KOffice 1.6.x nor the one from 2.2.x works." Do they not support the old format or are you running into some other error?

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, @Steven. I've just discovered StackExchange's inbox function O:-) I don't remember the errors exactly, but IIRC the 2.2 version said that the input format was not supported, and the 1.6 version said nothing but didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try koconverter ? This is part of the koffice libs

```
koconverter file.kwd file.odt
```

If it doesn't work there are any other command line tools that can do this, that means you have to do it manually with each document from the last koffice.

Answer (score 0):

I think of

- Open KWD documents with KWord/KOffice to check files are in readable fashion, since you have mentioned that opening of files with old version still works but make sure they are exportable as well.
- Save the documents to again .doc format, so that they are readable with OOffice.

I think with the later versions of KDE, KDE has chosen the native format to .doc (Actually OASIS format, which is native to OpenOffice)

Since it is just 75 documents, worth doing it, incase it is needed very urgently. If not, I think of writing a docstore parser which will batch convert the kwd files into openoffice compatible .doc format using the KWord API. These however mandates to have a good knowledge of C++, Qt, the Scribe framework, KDE (kdelibs), OpenDocument and finally kword itself.

http://www.koffice.org/developer/apidocs/

http://wiki.koffice.org/index.php?title=KWord/Tutorials/LoadingOdf#KWDocument